# A soultion $a$ for a system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was given the following system of equations:
$$ a + bc = -1$$
$$b+ac = -1$$
$$ c + ab = -1 $$
Which of these values of $a$ is one solution for this system of equations? $${-2,-1,0,2}$$

I managed to get the answer only by substituting each value that I was given into $a$. My question is how do I do this question without brute force?

Comment: I would begin by noting that $b + ac = c + ab \Rightarrow a(c-b) = c-b.$ Then...

Comment: If I divided by $c-b$ which gives me $a = 1$ which is not a solution.

Comment: There is another option. Can you spot it?

Comment: No, unfortunately I cannot see where you are trying to lead me to.

Comment: When is $a(c-b)$ equal to $c-b$? When $a = 1$, or...

Comment: I can only see one $a$ value. if $a = 0$, then $ 0 = c-b$ which is false. The other $a$ values do not work.

Comment: Why do you say $0 = c - b$ is false?

Comment: I am just assuming.

Comment: What if $a \neq 0$ and $c - b = 0$, then?

Comment: $ c = b$ but how can I say that $a = 0$. I cannot be sure that is the $a$ value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21641/discussion-between-luigi-d-and-aspiring-mathlete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of Luigi's comment, you can combine the second and third equations to get $b+ac=c+ab$. Manipulate this expression to get
$$a(c-b)=c-b \Rightarrow (a-1)(c-b)=0.$$
So either $a=1$ or $b=c$ are valid solutions, but $a=1$ is not given as a valid choice. Now if we plug $b=c$ into the first equation, we find 
$$ a + b^2 = -1 \Rightarrow a= -1-b^2.$$

From this we can see $a\le-1$. But in the case $a=-1$, $b=c=0$. However, these values do not solve the 2nd and 3rd equations. Since $b$ can't be 0, $a \lt-1$, and $a=-2$ is the only choice.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the approach adopted in comments etc gives $$(b-c)(a-1)=0$$Applying the same procedure to the other pairs of equations gives $$(a-b)(c-1)=0$$ and $$(c-a)(b-1)=0$$

Then, with $a\neq 1$ we must have $b=c$. There are two possibilities. First if $b=1$ then obviously we have the integer solution $c=1$ and $a=-2$ (which deals with the multiple choice)

To complete the solution note that the alternative is $a=b=c$ whence $a^2+a=-1$ or $(a+\frac 12)^2+\frac 34=0$, which has no real solutions (and solve the quadratic for the complex roots).